# how to toggle class in angular js on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to toggle a class on click, please find my below code.

```
<li class="dropdown" data-ng-class="sign-open">
  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-ng-click="signToogle()">Sign In <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px;">
    <form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-menu">
      <input id="user_username" type="text" name="user[username]" size="33" placeholder="Username">
      <input id="user_password" type="password" name="user[password]" size="33" placeholder="Password">
      <label class="checkbox muted hidden-tablet">
        <input type="checkbox">Remember Me</label>
      <input class="btn span3" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In">
    </form>

  </div>
</li>


//sign in show-hide
$scope.signToogle = function () {
    if ($scope.sign-open === "")
        $scope.class = "open";
    else
        $scope.class = "";
}
```

this js funciton will addclass open so if ul has open class as it's parent then it will be visible.
But don't know how can I make that **if click once then true and class append** and **if again clicked statement false and class will be removed**.

Comment: you can check using the condition of class. like this `if($scope.class ==='open'){ //remove class....}'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ng-class`

```
<div ng-class="{active: is_active}">Some div</div>

<button ng-click="is_active = !is_active" ng-init="is_active=false">Click to toggle</button>
```

Set or reset `$scope.is_active` when you click

Comment: what about js function side code, can you please help in it as well. and will it add class active, if i want to add class open should i change it to "{open: is_active}"

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Main', function($scope) {
  $scope.isOpen = false;
});
```

```css
.item span {
  display: none;
}
.item.close span.show-on-close {
  display: block;
}
.item.open span.show-on-open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="Main">
    <pre>isOpen: {{isOpen | json}}</pre>
    <span class="item" ng-class="{'open':isOpen, 'close':!isOpen}">
      <span class="show-on-open">open</span>
    <span class="show-on-close">close</span>
    </span>

    <button ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **NOTE**: variable in JavaScript can't contains the dash character 
>   so rename your `$scope.sign-open` to `$scope.signOpen`

you don't even have to define a function in the controller, you can do it like this:

`<span ng-class="{'open':!signOpen, '':signOpen}"></span>`

on click handler
`<button ng-click="signOpen = !signOpen">toggle</button>`

Comment: what about making it true and false on click

Comment: so please consider accepting the answer, if it answers your question

Comment: you are correct in your answer, but nikhil went for answer more fast, so upvote for you only is way for me to appreciate your good work.